# Some kind of measure

Tags: word, wordplay, rhyme

My prefix is a sign
My suffix describes mine
My infix is above you
But I'm just impromptu

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just to get some kind of a post in before others can snipe me, here's my

> **stopgap**

answer.

My prefix is a sign

> The STOP sign

My suffix describes mine

> a mine is a big gap in the ground

My infix is above you

> top

But I'm just impromptu
(and title)

> a *stopgap* or a *stopgap measure* is typically unplanned, and intended as a temporary solution only.

Comment: Well done, that's correct!